# How to make an accocation within SQL

Tags: mysql

ive moved away from java for a bit and started on SQL. Ive receieved a problem in which i really dont understand whats being asked is

" Use SQL statement to add to the database an association CUSTOMER Prefers
SUPPLIER to the database. Assume, that a customer can prefer more than one supplier and a supplier can be preferred by more than one customer"

Do they mean create a foreign key between the two when they say create an accociation? The only thread on this site is about an accocation between the same attribute of different values, so im just a bit confused on what the question is actually asking for

Thankyou for your time

ill post below my code for Customer and supplier if it helps anyone in explaining it

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER
(
    CUSTOMER_CODE   VARCHAR(5)  NOT NULL,
    COMPANY_NAME    VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    CONTACT_NAME    VARCHAR(30),
    CONTACT_TITLE   VARCHAR(30),
    ADDRESS         VARCHAR(60),
    CITY        VARCHAR(15),
    REGION      VARCHAR(15),
    POSTAL_CODE     VARCHAR(10),
    COUNTRY         VARCHAR(15),
    PHONE       VARCHAR(24),
    FAX         VARCHAR(24),
    CONSTRAINT PK_CUSTOMER PRIMARY KEY (CUSTOMER_CODE)
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE SUPPLIER
(
    COMPANY_NAME    VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    CONTACT_NAME    VARCHAR(30),
    CONTACT_TITLE   VARCHAR(30),
    ADDRESS         VARCHAR(60),
    CITY        VARCHAR(15),
    REGION      VARCHAR(15),
    POSTAL_CODE     VARCHAR(10),
    COUNTRY         VARCHAR(15),
    PHONE       VARCHAR(24),
    FAX         VARCHAR(24),
    HOME_PAGE       VARCHAR(500),
    CONSTRAINT PK_SUPPLIER PRIMARY KEY (COMPANY_NAME)  
);
```

Comment: If you don't understand the question you're asked, you should ask for help at the person asking that question - is this a homework task?

Comment: yea we had to make a database then modify some tables. Its good now i did some more research and its to do with a foriegn key. Thanks anyway